# Change Revit TextNote to sentence case. I have loads of text that needs to be changed from all caps to sentence case

Tags: c#, revit-api

Revit and Dynamo can change the case to all upper and all lower easily. I need to change loads of notes that are in all caps back to regular sentence case with first letter of each sentence capitalized. When I step through the code below its changing all the notes to sentence case but does not write back to the model. What am I missing?

```
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
{
    var uiDoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
    var doc = uiDoc.Document;

    try
    {
        using Transaction trans = new(doc, "Change to sentence case");

        var textNotes = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
            .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_TextNotes)
            .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
            .ToElements().Cast<TextNote>();

        var count = 0;
        trans.Start();
        foreach (var text in textNotes)
        {
            try
            {
                var currentFormattedText = text.GetFormattedText();
                var currentPlainText = text.GetFormattedText().GetPlainText();

                var output = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(currentPlainText.ToLower());
                currentFormattedText.SetPlainText(output);

                text.SetFormattedText(currentFormattedText);
                count++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message = ex.Message;
                return Result.Failed;
            }
        }
        trans.Commit();
        TaskDialog.Show("Change to Sentence Case", count + " text notes have been changed");
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
    catch (Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException)
    {
        return Result.Cancelled;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        message = ex.Message;
        return Result.Failed;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using` statement creates a `Transaction` object for a specific scope. The scope seems to be empty in this case, so the transaction disappears again before you have started to use it at all. Also, since no selection is taking place, you can eliminate the `catch` `OperationCanceledException`. And, once you do that, you can probably eliminate the entire `try`-`catch` exception handler. Just take some working example of a transaction in a `using` scope and paste you code into that, cf. [Handling Transactions and Transaction Groups](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.53).

Comment: thanks @Jeremy that tidied up the coded. For someone looking in the future the code above did work except on textNotes that had formatting already overwritten. I switched the output line to use a regex expression and that changed all the text ---    var lowerCase = currentPlainText.ToLower();
 var r = new Regex(@"(^[a-z])|\.\s+(.)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
 var result = r.Replace(lowerCase, s => s.Value.ToUpper());